# Can I remove the 'jar' task in gradle build?

Tags: gradle

When I use the code below, a file of jar will generate after gradle build.

```
apply plugin 'java'
```

Is there any settings won't generate the file of jar??

I can write a custom plugins,but the code below was wrong.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':crm.common')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I want find a way that donot generate the file of jar.
And can run compile in dependencies.
Is there any way can do that???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do that by 2 ways:

1. explicitly exclude the `jar` task from execution:

   `gradle build -x jar`
2. disable the `jar` task in `build.gradle`:

   `apply plugin: 'java'
   jar.enabled = false`

Comment: with the 2nd, how can I still be able to manually execute it singularly whenever I want? Launching `gradlew jar` I see `> Task :jar SKIPPED`

Comment: @elect in that case you'd need to remove the dependency from `build` to `jar` instead of disabling it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
configurations.archives.with {
    artifacts.remove artifacts.find { it.toString().contains("jar") }
}
```