# How to compile only java classes with gradle without producing JAR

Tags: java, gradle

I have my gradle projects, using java plugin.

In my case I would only need to call `classes` task to compile only java files, and not create JAR- would need this to speed up some process.

If i call `gradle classes` its also producing jar's (i suppose that task has dependencies therefore runs also building of jar's).

How would you recommend to do only compiling classes ? I dont want to override that task, because in some cases, i need also to run normal `gradle build` which produces JAR's.

I tried to skip jar with `gradle classes -x jar` but it seems omitting external dependencies and causing compilation errors.

Its a multiproject, and running `gradle classes` from root project is generating JAR in some projects as you can see here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DLkIfwhVMEb25uWHcwX1V1QUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202634/can-i-remove-the-jar-task-in-gradle-build

Comment: As far as I know, the creation of the jar is bound to the compilation of the classes. So calling `gradle compileJava` will also give you a jar. But maybe there is a trick on how to avoid this (which I just don't know). See this: https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test

Comment: you can disable the jar task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove the 'jar' task in gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202634/can-i-remove-the-jar-task-in-gradle-build)

Comment: @Zefick Actually it might sound same, but link you send havent resolved my issue, it caused different problems, it looks like when JAR task is skipped, external dependencies are omitted, which causes compilation errors. :(

Comment: Project dependencies won't work if you disable the `jar` task. Its like specifying a new module dependency and then going offline. Where should the dependency come from?

Answer (score 1):

See the diagram below from the [java plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html). The `classes` task should not call `jar` 
[image]

**EDIT**

Here's the result of running a simple gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Output:

```
> gradle classes
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see the `jar` task is not in the task graph

You could try adding the [task tree](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) plugin to your build and then run `gradle classes taskTree` to see what's causing the `jar` task to be added to the task graph

Comment: you can run it and you will see it does :)

Comment: here, pls check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DLkIfwhVMEb25uWHcwX1V1QUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it might be different for multiproject :(

Comment: The problem is not the multi-project build per se, but the usage of project dependencies. To compile a project you need all its dependencies, so for module dependencies the JAR files are downloaded and for project dependencies the JAR files are built. For each project, which is not a project dependency of another project, only the `classes` task (and its dependencies) will be executed. Even if you invoke a specific `classes` task via `gradle :<my-subproject>:classes`, you will still end up generating the JAR file for the project dependencies of `<my-subproject>`.

Comment: @lu.koerfer i think you are right, can you post what your wrote in comment, as answer so i mark it ? thx