# Only compile java classes in multi-project builds for inter-dependent projects

Tags: java, gradle, jar, multi-project

My question concerns inter-project dependencies and the resulting JARs

The project structure is akin to this

```
root
 -- :a
 -- :b
 -- :c
 -- :d
```

The dependencies are as follows (with `:d` having no dependencies)

```
a -> b -> c -> d
```

Compiling `:d`contains all the `*.class`files in `:d`. Compiling `:c`contains the sources generated for `:d`and `:c`. So far so good.

However, when I compile `root` it generates a JAR for `:d`, then compiles and generates a jar for `:c`, which includes the `CLASS` files of `:d`. This goes all the way to the top.

The `root`project will still only contain the compiled subprojects once, but the `build\libs` folder will contain all intermediate JARs as well.

I have run the build with `--profile` and noticed that the packaging of the JARs took up quite a bit of time from the total build process.

The dependent projects are included in their relevant `build.gradle` files like this (Example for `:b`and `:c`)

**Project C**

`dependencies {
    compile project(':d')
 }`

**Project B**

`dependencies {
    compile project(':c')
 }`

In reality the entire project consists of roughly 100 sub-projects and there are a large number of inter-dependent projects.

Is there any way to compile the `CLASS`files **without** generating the JAR?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The referenced possible duplicate question does not does with multi-project builds or inter-project dependencies.

Comment: `gradle build -x jar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove the 'jar' task in gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202634/can-i-remove-the-jar-task-in-gradle-build)

Comment: @AKSW I have just tried `gradle build -x jar` and it does not compile inter-project dependencies. I am trying to configure all the intermediate projects with `jar.enabled = false` except for the one responsible for compiling the distribution.

Comment: @AKSW applying the `jar.enabled = false` to the intermediate projects breaks the build. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had no choice than to add all the modules to the classpath manually and compile the entire module like that. Compile time is unreasonably high.

We're thinking of nicely decoupeling everything, having each module be a library which can be imported from a internal artifactory.